# Inserting dynamic text into form header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a multi page form and would like to change the headers on each page to reflect the projectID inserted on the first page of the form

```
<div data-role="page" id="chapter1">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Site Information ***(<!--want ProjectID entered here-->)*** <h1>
 </div><!--/header-->


 <div data-role="content">
 <Fieldset>
   <div class="_50">
     Project ID:<input type="text" name="ProjectID"> ***<!--ProjectID entered here-->***  
   </div> 
 <div class="_50">
    Project Name:<input type="text" name="ProjectName">
   </div>


<div data-role="page" id="chapter2">
 <div data-role="header">
 <h1>Samples Collected ***(<!--want ProjectID entered here-->)*** </h1>
 </div><!--/header-->

 <div data-role="content">
```

Being unfamilular with creating webforms I am at a loss as to how to accomplish this task. Assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't see a form here, just two text inputs. Do you want the ProjectID to be put into the `<h1>` tag as it is typed in, or are you trying to do a web form with a POST or GET ProjectID variable?

Comment: Is there a server side language that you are using?

Comment: I didn't think that you would want the whole form just the information I am trying to manipulate. I am using HTML5 with jQuery & jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Add to Your h1 fields a class or id, and then use it with:

```
$('#id_of_element).text('Your text to insert');
```

Or, if h1 is unique on every `#chapter`:

```
$('#chapter1 h1, #chapter2 h1').text('Your text to insert');
```

Comment: Apologize in advance but I have a dumb question... Where/how do I insert. like this?     <div data-role="page" id="chapter1">
     <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Site Information</h1>
      </div><!--/header-->
     <script>
     $('#chapter1 h1, #chapter2 h1').text("#ProjectID").val();
     </script>

Comment: I have no idea how You get your projectId. If you have it, You place the code in a function that can be called, when the ID is known, or just inside jQuery's `window.load`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("h1").html( $("h1") + " " + $("#ProjectID").val() )
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to dynamically change header, footer and content is to use `.trigger('pagecreate')` after appending markup into page.

> Basic page anatomy

```
<div data-role=page>
 <div data-role=header></div>
 <div data-role=content>stuff</div>
</div>
```

> jQuery Mobile

Replace old header with new one.

```
$('[data-role=header]').html('<div data-role=header><h1>new header</h1></div>');
```

Enhance the new markup.

```
$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
```

**[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/b5JkK/)**

Answer (score 0):

*Inserting dynamic text into form header* -- Try this way

```
 $("input[name='ProjectID']").on('keyup',function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     var h = $(this).closest("div[id^='chapter']").find("div[data-role='header']").find("h1");
     $(h).html( $(h).html() + " " + val);
 });
```

Comment: This helped a lot except how do I get the ProjectID in the header on the subsequent pages?

Answer (score 0):

First assignee a id to header

```
  <div data-role="header">
   <h1 id="header_content">Site Information ***(<!--want ProjectID entered here-->)***     <h1>
```

Script code for set ID

```
 var projectId=111;
 $('#header_content').html('Site Information ***('+projectId+')***');
```

Comment: Like this?  <div data-role="header">
 <h1 id="header_content">Site Information</h1>
 
<script>
   var ProjectID=111;
  function head() {
$('#header_content').html('Site Information ('+ProjectID+')');
  }
</script></div><!--/header-->
   <div data-role="content">
  <Fieldset>
    <div class="_50">
      Project ID:<input type="text" name="ProjectID" id="ProjectID" onchange="head()">
    </div>